# Передача данных через COM порт

Tags: c#, usb, com-port

Необходимо передать данные через COM порт на устройство, у которого вход только COM. Нашёл рабочий провод, который на одном конце USB, на другом - COM. При подключении к компьютеру, естественно, драйверы на него не находит. Написал небольшую программу, чтобы передавать данные, но на этапе поиска самого порта столкнулся с проблемой - устройство не находит. У меня 2 метода, который ищут устройство. 1 - вообще ничего не находит, 2 - находит устройства, который итак уже существуют и без подключения. Проблема поиска связана с тем, что не находит драйвер на этот провод? У меня нет диска с драйверами или чего-то подобного. Вот код, который написал

Получение списка:

```
public static class SerialPortService
{
    public static List<SerialPortInfo> GetSerialPortsInfo()
    {
        var retList = new List<SerialPortInfo>();

        var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort");
        var managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

        foreach (var port in managementObjectCollection)
        {
            var portName = port["DeviceID"].ToString();
            var caption = port["Caption"].ToString();
            var pnpDeviceId = port["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();

            retList.Add(new SerialPortInfo(portName, caption, pnpDeviceId));
        }

        retList.Sort();

        return retList;
    }

    public static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
    {
        List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        ManagementObjectCollection collection;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
            collection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
            ));
        }

        collection.Dispose();
        return devices;
    }
}
```

Передача данных:

```
public static class TransmitService
{
    public static void TransmitData(string data, string portName, int rate)
    {
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(data);
        if (rate <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rate), "Rate cant be less 0");

        using var port = new SerialPort(portName, rate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        try
        {
            port.Open();
            port.Write(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException($"An error occurred while transmitting data: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            port.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void TransmitData(string data, SerialPortInfo portInfo, int rate)
    {
        TransmitData(data, portInfo.Name, rate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Боль. На каком языке это написано?

Comment: @eri Пытался писать на C#, что и указал в тегах

Comment: COM порт работает по стандарту RS-232. Вдруг это поможет в поисках.

Comment: "RS-232" - не обязательно. На таких кабелях может быть и RS-422, 485, и др. Но это потом, а для начала нужно с драйвером разобраться, как в ответе eri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Откройте диспетчер устройств. Найдите неопознанное устройство. В его свойствах найдите параметры VEN_.... DEV_.... загуглите цифры "ven 1234 Dev 1234". Выбирайте сайт который внушает больше доверия и скачайте драйвер. После установки драйвера в свойствах устройства посмотрите номер порта.

Убедитесь что кабель компортовый, а не уарт или консоль от циски. Замкните rx и tx и если увидите эхо данных - можно подключать кабель к устройству.

Comment: Да, действительно. Проблема решилась установкой драйвера (который достаточно сложно ещё было найти...). Спасибо